# Getting Error in Building Open edX Android App in Android Studio. Why?

Tags: android, edx, openedx

Error:Unable to find module with Gradle path 'plugins/edx-app-gradle-plugin' (needed by module 'buildSrc'.)[image]
I'm following this websites...

https://github.com/edx/edx-app-android
http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/mobile.html

Comment: Please write in the question what did you do in your code, may you missed some steps.

Comment: I just clone it from GitHub. Then try to build it from Android studio. I haven't edit any code yet.

Answer (score 0):

Seems its not a Gradle issue & you are using unsupported Android Studio version. 
It supports Android Studio v2.3.x and below.

Check this https://github.com/edx/edx-app-android#frequently-asked-questions